# If $[A,B], A \in \mathcal{L}$ then does this imply that $B \in \mathcal{L}$?

Tags: lie-algebras

If $[A,B]$ and $A$ are in Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}$ then does this imply that $B \in \mathcal{L}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal{L}$ to be a subalgebra of some larger Lie algebra? In that case, no, and otherwise, the question does not really make sense.

Comment: The keyword for a counterexample is "ideal".

Comment: So in my head I have my Lie algebra, say for the orthogonal group. I find a random matrix and I know that it satisfies the condition on the left hand side. I would like to know if the right hand side holds. I felt that the answer was no but I couldn't think of a counter-example.

Comment: @JasonDeVito - Thank you very much, I knew I was missing something obvious...admittedly very obvious.

Comment: @Uther:  It always seems obvious in retrospect ;-).  If you'd like to write up an answer yourself, please feel free.

Comment: My keyword for counterexample is "$0$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ideal $I$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is a subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
[\mathfrak{g},I] \subseteq I.
\end{equation}
The ideal $I$ forms a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Therefore if the Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}$ in the question is some ideal and one chooses any $A \in \mathcal{L}$ and some $B$ in the larger algebra then we would get
\begin{equation}
[A,B] \in \mathcal{L}.
\end{equation}
even for $B \notin \mathcal{L}$.

This provides a counter example and so the answer to the question is a (somewhat resounding) NO!